# Works on development server but it doesn't on Google App Engine (Sessions)

Tags: java, google-app-engine, session

I have this code that works just fine on the development server but 
when I deploy the application, the session isn't created. 
What am I doing wrong?

HttpSession session = req.getSession(true); 
session.setAttribute("loggedIn", new String("true"));

Edit:

The sessions are enabled. 
What I realized now is that the _ah_SESSION variable is not being 
created, not even on the development server (although it works).

Comment: If any of the answers helped out, can you accept one ? This closes out the question.

Answer (score 0):

Did you enable sesssion in APE. See instructions here,

http://code.google.com/intl/en-US/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig.html#Enabling_Sessions

Comment: What else can it be? Do I need to "save" it or something?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can get the session in GAE:

```
this.getThreadLocalRequest().getSession();
```